# mysql count how many times the same value appears across multiple colums

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

during a group project we recent sent out a survey regarding the site we're building. I've put the data into a mysql database and i'm trying to figure out how to count how many times certain scores was given in each category
the table looks like this

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Design          | Ease of use  | Responsiveness    |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+
| 5               | 5            | 5
| 4               | 4            | 4
| 3               | 3            | 3
| 2               | 2            | 2
| 1               | 1            | 1
| 5               | 4            | 2
| 5               | 4            | 4
| 3               | 3            | 3
| 1               | 2            | 2
| 1               | 2            | 2
```

I've found a query that works for one colum

```
SELECT Design, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table GROUP BY Design
```

I would then get

```
Design | num
------------- 
 5     | 3
 4     | 1
 3     | 2
 2     | 1  
 1     | 3
```

If i were to try

```
SELECT Design, COUNT(*) AS num1, Ease of use, COUNT(*) as num2 FROM table 
GROUP BY Design, Ease of use
```

The table gets totally messed up.

What I want is to get

```
Design | num1 | Ease of use  | num2 | Responsiveness | num3 
------------- --------------------------------------------------
 5     | 3    | 5            | 1    | 5              | 1
 4     | 1    | 4            | 3    | 4              | 2
 3     | 2    | 3            | 2    | 3              | 2
 2     | 1    | 2            | 3    | 2              | 4
 1     | 3    | 1            | 1    | 1              | 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: You get design has a score of 5 3 times ease of use a score of 5 1 time and responsiveness a score of 5 1 time and so on I don't see how that is messed up you get your results? group by num1, num2, num3 and count(fieldname) so count(Design) as num1

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot the values and then aggregate.  In MySQL, that typically uses `union all`:

```
select val, count(*)
from ((select design as val from table) union all
      (select ease_of_use from table) union all
      (select responsiveness from table
     ) der
group by val
order by val desc;
```

For what you want to get, you can do:

```
select val, sum(design) as design, sum(ease_of_use) as ease_of_use,
       sum(responsiveness) as responsiveness
from ((select design as val, 1 as design, 0 as ease_of_use, 0 as responsiveness from table) union all
      (select ease_of_use, 0, 1, 0 from table) union all
      (select responsiveness, 0, 0, 1 from table
     ) der
group by val
order by val desc;
```

I see no reason to repeat the value three times.

Answer (score 1):

Use a synthesized table with the different values, and join this with subqueries that get the counts of each score.

```
SELECT nums.num AS Design, t1.count AS num1,
       nums.num AS `Ease of Use`, t2.count AS num2,
       nums.num AS Responsiveness, t3.count AS num3
FROM (SELECT 1 AS num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) AS nums
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Design, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Design) AS t1 ON t1.Design = nums.num
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `Ease of Use`, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY `Ease of Use`) AS t2 ON t2.`Ease of Use` = nums.num
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Responsiveness, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Responsiveness) AS t3 ON t3.Responsiveness = nums.num
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1f019/5)

Comment: Subqueries in the SELECT clause would look much simpler.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I tend to avoid correlated subqueries, I'm under the impression MySQL doesn't optimize them well. I really wanted to do the pivot version that Gordon Linoff posted, but I was having trouble coming up with it.

Comment: "I tend to avoid correlated subqueries, I'm under the impression MySQL doesn't optimize them well" Without indexes the LEFT JOIN's in MySQL will perform just as badly as correlated subqueries.

Comment: I also just find joins easier to read, subqueries in the SELECT are complicated.

Comment: @RaymondNijland In this case (even with millions of rows) each subquery returns only 5 rows. So it's not a big deal to join then without indexes. It's three times full table scan (+sort). While my correlated query solution will need 3*5=15 times full table scans. But i doubt we are talking about millions of rows here.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three ways:

```
select s.score,
  (select count(*) from tbl where `Design`         = s.score) as `Design`,
  (select count(*) from tbl where `Ease of use`    = s.score) as `Ease of use`,
  (select count(*) from tbl where `Responsiveness` = s.score) as `Responsiveness`
from (
  select Design as score from tbl
  union select `Ease of use` from tbl
  union select Responsiveness from tbl
) s
order by score desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/002303/2

```
select s.score,
  (select count(*) from tbl where `Design`         = s.score) as `Design`,
  (select count(*) from tbl where `Ease of use`    = s.score) as `Ease of use`,
  (select count(*) from tbl where `Responsiveness` = s.score) as `Responsiveness`
from (select 1 as score union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) s
order by score desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/002303/4

```
select s.score,
  sum(`Design`         = score) as `Design`,
  sum(`Ease of use`    = score) as `Ease of use`,
  sum(`Responsiveness` = score) as `Responsiveness`
from (select 1 as score union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) s
cross join tbl t
group by s.score
order by s.score desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/002303/5

They all return the same result:

```
| score | Design | Ease of use | Responsiveness |
|-------|--------|-------------|----------------|
|     5 |      3 |           1 |              1 |
|     4 |      1 |           3 |              2 |
|     3 |      2 |           2 |              2 |
|     2 |      1 |           3 |              4 |
|     1 |      3 |           1 |              1 |
```

As @futureweb wrote in the comment, I don't see a reason to repeat the score three times. Though you can if you want using aliases.

If you have millions of rows ;-) and no indexes you would want to get the result with only one table scan. This is possible with:

```
select
  sum(`Design` = 1) as d1,
  sum(`Design` = 2) as d2,
  sum(`Design` = 3) as d3,
  sum(`Design` = 4) as d4,
  sum(`Design` = 5) as d5,
  sum(`Ease of use` = 1) as e1,
  sum(`Ease of use` = 2) as e2,
  sum(`Ease of use` = 3) as e3,
  sum(`Ease of use` = 4) as e4,
  sum(`Ease of use` = 5) as e5,
  sum(`Responsiveness` = 1) as r1,
  sum(`Responsiveness` = 2) as r2,
  sum(`Responsiveness` = 3) as r3,
  sum(`Responsiveness` = 4) as r4,
  sum(`Responsiveness` = 5) as r5
from tbl
```

This will return the data you need, but not in the form you'd like:

```
| d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | e5 | r1 | r2 | r3 | r4 | r5 |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|  3 |  1 |  2 |  1 |  3 |  1 |  3 |  2 |  3 |  1 |  1 |  4 |  2 |  2 |  1 |
```

So you would need to post process it.